# ¿Como capturar una excepcion lanzada en un Task? C#

Tags: c#, async, task

¿Como puedo capturar las excepciones de una task declarada de esta manera `Task task = new Task(() => Metodo())`? he intentado poner un try catch donde declaro la task pero cuando sale una excepcion la aplicacion se congela. aqui les dejo mi codigo:

```
private void RunForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = new Task(() => _renamer.RenameFiles(_progress), _token);
        try
        {
            _progress = new Progress<float>();
            _progress.ProgressChanged += _progress_ProgressChanged;
            task.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }


public void RenameFiles(IProgress<float> progressReporter)
    {
        try
        {
            float progres = 0;
            int totalFiles;
            var files = extensionsToSearch.SelectMany((ext) => _directory.GetFiles(ext));
            var groups = files.GroupBy((file) => file.Name.Split('.')[0]);
            totalFiles = files.Count();
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                string name = "";
                foreach (var file in group.OrderByDescending((f) => f.Extension))
                {
                    if (file.Extension.Equals(".xml"))
                    {
                        var data = ComprobanteReader.Deserialize(file.FullName);
                        if (data is null)
                        {
                            throw new Exception($"No se ha podido leer el archivo {file.FullName}");
                        }
                        name = data.Receptor.Nombre;
                    }
                    file.MoveTo($@"{_path}\{file.Name.Split('.')[0]} {name}{file.Extension}");
                    progres++;
                    progressReporter.Report(progres * 100 / totalFiles);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            progressReporter.Report(100);  
            throw new Exception($"{ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException ex)
        {
            progressReporter.Report(100);
            throw new Exception($"{ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yo hice una app con task y un BackgroundWorker, deberia ser similar y creo que la parte que te hace falta es llamar al Cancel para cancelar el hilo del Task, en la exception deberias poner task.Cancel()

Comment: Es posible que esté sucediendo un deadlock.

Comment: [`Start`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) no lanza las excepciones que se produzcan dentro de la ejecución de la tarea. [`Wait`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) sí.